# How to map resource A to resource B via REST call?

Tags: rest, post, put

I have 2 resources that are `Many-To-Many` related.
One resource is `users` and the other is `roles`. A `user` can have different `roles` assigned, whereas a `role` can have different `users` assigned.

- `/users` will return all users
- `/roles` will return all roles

The `Many-To-Many` relation allows me to use the following resource paths:

- `/users/1/roles` will return all roles assigned to user with id 1
- `/roles/1/users` will return all users assigned to role with id 1

Now let's say I want to assign a role with id 2 to user with id 1.

I have two different ideas:

- `PUT /users/1/roles/2 (No request body, as no use)`. This approach would be quite readable and clearly idempotent. Also I don't expect a response. But it seems weird not to send a request body with a PUT request.
- `POST /users/1/roles (Role object as request body)`  This approach seems technically more correct. But it's not obvious that I want to map an already existing role. It seems more that I create a role for this user. Also it seems very useless to attach an already existing role to the request. A `BadRequest` because I try to add a non-existing role, would be very confusing.

Both seem actually not really correct to me...

How is this done in a understandable REST conform way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use `PUT` verb since you are updating the roles assigned to your user.
But I prefer using the request body to specify the full list of roles that I want to assign to this users.

```
PUT /users/1/roles (list of assigned Role objects as request body)
```

`POST` verb, as you said, is generally used for creating new object.

Also, here are additional advises from colleagues which I find useful: [RESTful APIs from Scratch: Lessons Learnt (so far)](https://blogs.sap.com/2012/06/03/restful-apis-from-scratch-lessons-learnt-so-far/)

Comment: This would mean that I need to make a `GET /users/1/roles` first so I could add one specific role to the list to `PUT /users/1/roles` again. I don't know about this.

Comment: Yes. That is the general pattern.

Comment: I also will have the same constellation with `Roles` and `Permissions.` The whole system will have different services which will define their own permissions. As the system grows, it could happen, that a role might have over 100 permissions. If I now want to add on permission, this seems a lot of necessary data transfer. It really don't seem to be salable.

Comment: I just had another thought: When using `PUT /users/1/roles` I always would need to provide the complete list. If I would use `POST/ users/1/roles` I only could provide a partial list which would get added to the resource, am I correct? `POST` should be correct as I would create a "new resource" for this user

Comment: Yes, it makes sense.